# magento 1.7.0.2 shipping address will revert to billing address when i edit order

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, shipping-address, edit-order

When i place an order on the front end, using a shipping address that is different from the billing address, upon editing the same order on the admin panel, the shipping address will change to the same as the billing address even though when i place the order i use a different shipping address from the billing address. Shouldn't the shipping address remain?

I'm having an issue with a clean install of 1.7.0.2 without any extension installed.

Here is how to reproduce this issue:

1. Sign up for an account and Place and order on this fresh magento install where shipping address is different from billing address
2. logon to admin panel, and load up the order, and i can see that the shipping address is different from the billing address
3. when i click edit to edit the order, "same as billing address will be checked" and the shipping address will be defaulted to the billing address.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I have this very same problem, on a clean 1.7 installation. Also, I'm wondering why this was put "On Hold"? The OP clearly describes their problem and how to reproduce the issue, so why was the question put "On Hold"?